# Meaning of "They were meant to have them"?

Tags: meaning, american-english, british-english

```
There are five pups. 
One for each of the stark children. 
The direwolf  is a sigil of your house. 
They were meant to have them.
```

Can you please explain the meaning of "They were meant to have them"?

Comment: It was destined, it was "in the stars".

Comment: What part of it is troubling you? Can you elaborate? The question stands the risk of being closed (shortly).

Answer (score 1):

They (the children) were meant (destined, intended) to have them (the dogs).

So, who meant for this to happen? A higher power.

The coincidences or the "proof" that it was meant to be: 5 children and 5 dogs, plus the sign of your house is a wild dog.

"___was meant to be" is a statement that implies that an occurrence or coincidence was intended or predestined by {God, The Fates, Destiny, a spiritual life force, whatever the speaker believes controls the universe.}

Source: [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/be-meant-to-be)

> if something is meant to be, it seems certain to happen, usually because it has been decided by God or other forces that people believe cannot be controlled

It is a common idiom. Unless you know the speaker or the context, it is not clear how literal or figurative the speaker is being (i.e. it can range from "Look, it all fits, so the children should keep the dogs," to "The Hand of God came down and placed these dogs here so your children would have them," to anything in between.)